# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0

Tags: cyrillic, utf8

I get the following error trying to compile a file with bulgarian text on Ubuntu 20.04 with tex-live. I use kile to compile.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/texliveonfly", line 360, in <module>
    (output, returnCode)  = compileTex()
  File "/usr/bin/texliveonfly", line 277, in compileTexDoc
    return readFromProcess(process)
  File "/usr/bin/texliveonfly", line 292, in readFromProcess
    line = getProcessLine()
  File "/usr/bin/texliveonfly", line 285, in <lambda>
    getProcessLine = lambda : frombytesifpy3(process.stdout.readline())
  File "/usr/bin/texliveonfly", line 44, in <lambda>
    frombytesifpy3 = lambda b = None : b.decode("UTF-8") if py3 and b != None else b
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 19: invalid continuation byte
```

Minimum example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, bulgarian]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
 \item {\em Решение.} Тази стъпка използва компресираната и 
 факторизирана матрица от коефициенти на системата и дясната страна,
 за намиране на решението. Изчислителната сложност на тази стъпка 
 е $O(rn)$. 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

If I add an empty line between the \item row and the next, it compiles, but that adds an unwanted new paragraph and in the actual file I have other code that breaks it too.

I.e. if I change \item as below it will suddenly start compiling:

```
...
\begin{enumerate}
 \item {\em Решение.} Тази стъпка използва компресираната и 

 факторизирана матрица от коефициенти на системата и дясната страна,
 за намиране на решението. Изчислителната сложност на тази стъпка 
 е $O(rn)$. 
\end{enumerate}
...
```

I am on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS with tex-live and have just upgraded from 18.04. On another computer with Ubuntu 20.04 same text compiles without a problem as a part of a bigger file.

Full Output log of the compile command:

```
*****
*****     PDFLaTeX output: 
*****     cd "/home/iict/Documents/test_not_working"
*****     texliveonfly -a -interaction=nonstopmode not_working.tex
*****
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./not_working.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-02-14>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2aenc.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t2aenc.dfu)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/switch.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-bulgarian/bulgarian.ldf))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def)
(./not_working.aux (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2acmr.fd)
)
Overfull \hbox (0.53506pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 9--13
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/texliveonfly", line 360, in <module>
    (output, returnCode)  = compileTex()
  File "/usr/bin/texliveonfly", line 277, in compileTexDoc
    return readFromProcess(process)
  File "/usr/bin/texliveonfly", line 292, in readFromProcess
    line = getProcessLine()
  File "/usr/bin/texliveonfly", line 285, in <lambda>
    getProcessLine = lambda : frombytesifpy3(process.stdout.readline())
  File "/usr/bin/texliveonfly", line 44, in <lambda>
    frombytesifpy3 = lambda b = None : b.decode("UTF-8") if py3 and b != None else b
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 19: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: try without texliveonfly, use directly pdflatex.

Comment: Yep, that actually worked. I guess it is a texliveonfly bug. You can write it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: I openned this issue on texliveonfly, linking to here. https://github.com/maphy-psd/texliveonfly/issues/6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error looks like a python error, so try without texliveonfly, use directly pdflatex.